# why angular application is able to download only some of the svg files from spring server

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to serve my packaged angular files from the server.

I have a svg file named *some-svg-image.svg*. I see that it exists in the spring application static folder and was added a random addition to the name like this:

> 'some-svg-image.eruhfdf78fsd7dgf78sd87dsf8.svg'

In the html the asset name was changed accordingly:

```
<img src="../../assets/images/some-svg-image.svg">
```

to

```
<img src="./some-svg-image.eruhfdf78fsd7dgf78sd87dsf8.svg">
```

when looking at network tab I get **404** http error.

why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the **hyphen sign** in the name.

Replace / remove hyphens:

```
somesvgimg.svg
```